# Why does variable independence imply set independence?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I often see written that for two discrete random variables  $X_1$ and $X_2$ that are independent
 $$P(X_1 \in A\ \text{ and } \ X_2 \in B) = P(X_1 \in A)P(X_2 \in B)$$ because
 $$P(X_1 = x_1 \ \text{ and } \ X_2 = x_2) = P(X_1 = x_1)P(X_2 = x_2)$$
Why does the second necessarily *imply* the first?

Comment: Just integrate/sum $(2)$ over $A\times B$.

Comment: It's not too hard to see actually, for this I suggest that you first write down what it means by definition for a finite family of discrete random variables to be independent (do it really thorough) and then write down what has to hold equivalently in your second line ($\forall x_1,x_2....$)

Answer (score 2):

This only holds when the variables are *discrete*.

In that case, you can produce the first equation by adding together a finite number of instances of the second one, one for each $(x_1,x_2)\in A\times B$.